# import and export multiple components via functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, export

I have created a file named `index.js`I am going to use this file as main importing and exporting file
I have two components including login and header in my project and i have exported them as following method at end of each file:

```
export {Login};
```

```
export {Header};
```

Then i exported both of them in `index.js` as following method:

```
export * from './login';
```

```
export * from './header';
```

And at the end i have imported both of them in `App.js` by this method:

```
import {Login, Header} from './components/index';
```

It doesn't work and i am getting error :
Invariant violation:Element type is invalid.
Does anybody knows which part i made mistake?

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to achieve what you wanted. You could instead:

```
export default Login;
```

```
export default Header;
```

on each files and import it on your index.js

```
import Login from './login';
import Header from './header';

...

export {
 Login,
 Header
}
```

```
import {Login, Header} from './components'; // you could eliminate the index
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using class style components, you can do

```
class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <Text> Text and other tags here </Text>
        )
    }
}
export default Login;
```

Then in your App.js

```
import Login from '../components/Login.js';  //or wherever this component lives
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume our folder structure looks like this.

```
|- elements
   |- Login.js
   |- Header.js
   |- index.js
|- components
   |- App.js
```

1.export the components

```
// ./elements/Login.js
export { Login }; 
// ./elements/Header.js
export { Header };
```

2.import and export all the components in index.js

```
// ./elements/index.js
export { Loading } from './Login';
export { Header } from './Header';
```

import in any file we need

```
// ./components/App.js
import { Login, Header } from '../elements';
```